# Call recording on Samsung

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder, recording, phone-call

There is a problem.
I have implemented call recording in this way:

```
 mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
 mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
 mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(audioFile.getAbsolutePath());
 mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Then, after testing on few devices I noticed, that Samsung actually doesn't record the sound stream at all and throws an exception.
I've changed code above, so now it's looks kinda like:

```
if (Build.MANUFACTURER.toLowerCase().contains("samsung")) {
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
    } else {
            mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
        }
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(audioFile.getAbsolutePath());
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

So, it's working. But it makes recording only for my voice and ignores my interlocutor.
Any thoughts how to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked for permissions? Specifically, `Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO`

Comment: Yes, I checked everything I know about before creating this topic